# Composer Error Updating Craft CMS 3 from RC13 to 14/15

Tags: php, composer

PHP 7.0.28 / MySQL 5.6.38 / Craft Pro 3.0.0-RC13

While trying to update I get this error:

```
Error: An error occurred

Output: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- The requested package codeception/codeception could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
Problem 2
- The requested package codeception/mockery-module could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
Problem 3
- The requested package codeception/specify could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
Problem 4
- The requested package codeception/verify could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
see for more details.
- It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read for further common problems.
Running update with --no-dev does not mean require-dev is ignored, it just means the packages will not be installed. If dev requirements are blocking the update you have to resolve those problems.
```

My composer.json file:

```
{
  "name": "craftcms/cms",
  "description": "Craft CMS",
  "version": "3.0.0-RC13",
  "keywords": [
    "cms",
    "craftcms",
    "yii2"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://craftcms.com",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "support": {
    "email": "support@craftcms.com",
    "issues": "https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/",
    "source": "https://github.com/craftcms/cms",
    "docs": "https://github.com/craftcms/docs",
    "rss": "https://github.com/craftcms/cms/releases.atom"
  },
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-dom": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-mbstring": "*",
    "ext-openssl": "*",
    "ext-pcre": "*",
    "ext-pdo": "*",
    "ext-zip": "*",
    "composer/composer": "~1.5.2",
    "craftcms/oauth2-craftid": "~1.0.0",
    "craftcms/plugin-installer": "~1.5.0",
    "craftcms/server-check": "~1.1.0",
    "creocoder/yii2-nested-sets": "~0.9.0",
    "danielstjules/stringy": "~3.1.0",
    "elvanto/litemoji": "^1.3.1",
    "enshrined/svg-sanitize": "~0.8.2",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.3.0",
    "league/flysystem": "~1.0.35",
    "league/oauth2-client": "~2.2.1",
    "mikehaertl/php-shellcommand": "~1.2.5",
    "pixelandtonic/imagine": "~0.7.1.2",
    "seld/cli-prompt": "~1.0.3",
    "twig/twig": "~2.4.4",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.14.2",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.10",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.1.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-queue": "~2.0.1",
    "zendframework/zend-feed": "~2.8.0",
    "craftcms/cms": "3.0.0-RC15",
    "bugsnag/bugsnag": "v3.9.0",
    "craftcms/redactor": "1.0.1",
    "dolphiq/redirect": "1.0.15",
    "nystudio107/craft-cookies": "1.1.9",
    "superbig/craft3-bugsnag": "2.0.0",
    "superbig/craft3-templateselect": "2.0.0",
    "topshelfcraft/supersort": "3.0.1"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "codeception/codeception": "~2.3.3",
    "codeception/mockery-module": "~0.2.2",
    "codeception/specify": "~0.4.6",
    "codeception/verify": "~0.3.3"
  },
  "provide": {
    "bower-asset/bootstrap": "3.3.* | 3.2.* | 3.1.*",
    "bower-asset/jquery": "3.2.*@stable | 3.1.*@stable | 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable",
    "bower-asset/inputmask": "~3.2.2 | ~3.3.5",
    "bower-asset/punycode": "1.3.*",
    "bower-asset/yii2-pjax": "~2.0.1"
  },
  "suggest": {
    "ext-imagick": "Adds support for more image processing formats and options.",
    "ext-iconv": "Adds support for more character encodings than PHP’s built-in mb_convert_encoding() function, which Craft will take advantage of when converting strings to UTF-8.",
    "ext-intl": "Adds rich internationalization support."
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "craft\\": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this on several installations by changing the PHP and Yii versions to match what the system was running. It seemed to get out of sync now and then so had to keep on top of it at first on all of the Craft 3 installations. Once it's handled it doesn't pose a problem in the future.